# SBT: generate code for submodule before compilation

Tags: scala, sbt, code-generation

I have the following issue with build.sbt configuration.
I need to generate some code before compilation.
That's how it works now.

```scala
lazy val rootProject = project.in(file("."))

lazy val rootSourceGenerator = Def.task {
  val f: File = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "com" / "myproject" / "Version.scala"

  IO.write(
    f,
    s"""package com.myproject
       |
       |object Version {
       |  some code ...
       |}
       |""".stripMargin
  )

  Seq(f)
}

inConfig(Compile)(
  Seq(
    sourceGenerators += rootSourceGenerator
  ))
```

And for now I need to make the same thing for a new submodule.

```
lazy val rootProject = project.in(file(".")).dependsOn(submodule)
lazy val submodule = project.in(file("submodule"))

lazy val submoduleSourceGenerator = Def.task {
  val f: File = (sourceManaged in (submodule, Compile)).value / "com" / "myproject" / "SubmoduleVersion.scala"

  IO.write(
    f,
    s"""package com.myproject
       |
       |object SubmoduleVersion {
       |  some code ...
       |}
       |""".stripMargin
  )

  Seq(f)
}

inConfig(submodule / Compile)(
  Seq(
    sourceGenerators += submoduleSourceGenerator
  ))
```

And `inConfig(submodule / Compile)` doesn't work. Error is about unknown syntax for `/`.
Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple solutions but the cleanest is following in my opinion.

Create an [AutoPlugin](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Plugins.html#Creating+an+auto+plugin) in `project/GenerateVersion.scala` with following content

```scala
import sbt.Keys._
import sbt._

object GenerateVersion extends AutoPlugin {
  override def trigger = noTrigger

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = {
    Seq(
      sourceGenerators in Compile += Def.task {
        val f: File =
          (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "com" / "myproject" / "Version.scala"
        IO.write(
          f,
          s"""package com.myproject
                 |
                 |object Version {
                 |}
                 |""".stripMargin
        )
        Seq(f)
      }.taskValue
    )
  }
}
```

Enable newly created plugin `GenerateVersion` for all projects/submodules that need `Version.scala` generated. It can be done as following in `build.sbt`

```scala
lazy val sub = project
  .in(file("sub"))
  .enablePlugins(GenerateVersion)

lazy val root = project
  .in(file("."))
  .enablePlugins(GenerateVersion)
  .aggregate(sub)
```

`aggregate(sub)` is added to run tasks in `sub` module when root tasks are triggered. For example, `sbt compile` will run both `sbt "root/compile" "sub/compile"`

This solution is easier to share across multiple SBT projects in the form of SBT plugin.

Also, you might be interested in [sbt-builtinfo](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-buildinfo) plugin

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Ivan Stanislavciuc! But I've found another solution.
Just add all of the following content to `/subproject/build.sbt`

```
lazy val submoduleSourceGenerator = Def.task {
  val f: File = (sourceManaged in Compile).value / "com" / "myproject" / "SubmoduleVersion.scala"

  IO.write(
    f,
    s"""package com.myproject
       |
       |object SubmoduleVersion {
       |  some code ...
       |}
       |""".stripMargin
  )

  Seq(f)
}

inConfig(Compile)(
  Seq(
    sourceGenerators += submoduleSourceGenerator
  ))
```